# Error with pyenv

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, pyenv

Our application uses pyenv which is provided by development team.

(Since it is required by app, we are not suppose to add it in .bashrc or other files

Consider I have copied "pyenv" at `/root/dsp_pyenv` directory.

Contents of above directory look like below :

```
[root@dsp-centos dsp_pyenv]# pwd
/root/dsp_pyenv
[root@dsp-centos dsp_pyenv]# ls
bin  CHANGELOG.md  completions  libexec  LICENSE  plugins  README.md  shims  test  versions
[root@dsp-centos dsp_pyenv]#
```

Along with that, they have given the below instructions before starting actual app.

1. `export PYENV_ROOT="/root/dsp_pyenv/"`
2. `export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"`
3. `export PYENV_VERSION=2.7.6`
4. `eval "$(pyenv init -)"`

But after executing first three successfully, for 4th instruction, I am getting below error :

```
[root@dsp-centos dsp_pyenv]# eval "$(pyenv init -)"
pyenv: no such command `init'
[root@dsp-centos dsp_pyenv]#
```

Also, when I am trying to execute just "pyenv", I am getting below error :

```
[root@dsp-centos ~]# pyenv
/root/dsp_pyenv/bin/pyenv: line 81: pyenv---version: command not found
/root/dsp_pyenv/bin/pyenv: line 81: pyenv-help: command not found

[root@dsp-centos ~]#
```

Please guide me through this.

Answer (score 2):

Try to put

```
export PATH="$(pyenv root)/shims:$PATH"
```

in your .zshrc (if you use zsh) or any other equivalent.
pyenv unable to work without those shims